# R Shiny Leaflet Marker Zoom Issues

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, markers

I want to be able to double click on a custom marker and have the map recenter and zoom. Im not sure if it should be doing it automatically and just isnt or if i need a special code.

Below is my current marker code:
Thanks!

```
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%")) 
server <- function(input, output){
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    m <- leaflet(wins) %>% addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap)
    m %>% setView(-72.690940, 41.651426, zoom = 12)
    m %>% addMarkers(~lng, ~lat,
      icon = greenLeafIcon,
      popup = paste("Where:", wins$Where,"<br>", "What:", wins$What,"<br>", "Who:", wins$Who,"<br>", "Why:", wins$Why,"<br>", "Order Date:", wins$OrderDate,"<br>", "Go Live Date:", wins$GoLiveDate, "<br>","<a href='",wins$link,"' target='_blank'>",wins$link,"</a>"),
      clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(color="#0017bb"),
      centerMap
      label = wins$Name,
      labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = F)) 
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)

> dput(wins)
structure(list(Name = structure(c(9L, 6L, 11L, 4L, 2L, 10L, 5L, 
3L, 8L, 1L, 7L), .Label = c("Brigam", "Brown", "Buffalo", "Cornell", 
"Maine Medical", "MGH", "Middlesex", "North Maine", "Tufts", 
"UVM", "Yale"), class = "factor"), Where = structure(c(9L, 6L, 
11L, 4L, 2L, 10L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 7L), .Label = c("Brigam", "Brown", 
"Buffalo", "Cornell", "Maine Medical", "MGH", "Middlesex Medical Hospital", 
"North Maine", "Tufts", "UVM", "Yale"), class = "factor"), What = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "saple3", class = "factor"), 
    Who = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = "RML-  SAM-", class = "factor"), 
    Why = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = "sample", class = "factor"), OrderDate = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Q1", class = "factor"), 
    GoLiveDate = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Q2", class = "factor"), lat = c(42.349598, 
    42.361542, 41.303229, 40.764991, 41.819064, 44.47972, 43.653243, 
    42.886447, 47.140694, 42.33597, 41.55466), lng = c(-71.063541, 
    -71.0688334, -72.933826, -73.95479, -71.408277, -73.194072, 
    -70.276184, -78.87836, -68.269043, -71.10766, -72.64815), 
    link = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L), .Label = c("http:\\\\www.google.com", "http:\\\\www.google.org", 
    "https://google.com"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Name", "Where", "What", 
"Who", "Why", "OrderDate", "GoLiveDate", "lat", "lng", "link"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Comment: Can you please make your code reproducible by adding the result of `dput(wins)` to the question?

Comment: @GGamba just did thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately AFAIK there is no `double_click` event in leaflet (I'd love to be proved wrong).

If you are ok with a single click, we can do:

```
server <- function(input, output){
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        m <- leaflet(wins) %>% 
            addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>% 
            addMarkers(~lng, ~lat,
                       #icon = 'greenLeafIcon',
                       popup = paste("Where:", wins$Where,"<br>", "What:", wins$What,"<br>", "Who:", wins$Who,"<br>", "Why:", wins$Why,"<br>", "Order Date:", wins$OrderDate,"<br>", "Go Live Date:", wins$GoLiveDate, "<br>","<a href='",wins$link,"' target='_blank'>",wins$link,"</a>"),
                       clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(color="#0017bb"),
                       #centerMap,
                       label = ~Name,
                       labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = F)) 
    })

    observe({
        click <- input$map_marker_click
        zoom <- isolate(input$map_zoom)
        if(is.null(click))
            return()

        leafletProxy('map') %>% 
            setView(click$lng, click$lat, zoom = zoom)
    })
}
```

What it does it's `observe` the `map_marker_click` event, when that happen `leafletProxy()` will update the `'map' output` to the specified `lng`, `lat` and `zoom`. We need to isolate `input$zoom`, otherwise the `observe` would launch every time we change the zoom, causing weird behaviors.

Comment: where can I see the map_marker_click input or the map_zoom? Is it something I have to define?

Comment: They should be defined when you add a leaflet 'object', but I'm not so sure this is still the case, the library may have changed in this last 2+ years